# python cgi on IIS

Tags: python, iis, asp-classic, vbscript, cgi

How do you set up IIS so that you can call python scripts from asp pages?

Ok, so I found the answer to that question here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494

So on to my next question: How do you call a cgi script from within classic asp (vb) code? Particularly one which is not in the web root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that VBScript as hosted by IIS has any way of executing an external process.  If you are using python as an AXscripting engine then you could just use the sys module.  If the script you're calling is actually meant to be a cgi script you'll have to mimic all the environment variables that the cgi uses.  The alternative is to put the script on the python path, import it and hope that it is modular enough that you can call the pieces you need and bypass the cgi handling code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it [this way](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121638/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/082201-1.shtml).